# How to push same branch to same branch if we have multiple branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a parent repository having branches `master` `stage` & `develop` along with child repository say as **submodule** which has same branches `master` `stage` & `develop`, I made commits in `stage` branch in child repository(**submodule**) and try to push the changes to `stage` branch in parent repository but still the changes are not reflecting in the GitHub.

note:- Its working for parent repo's `master` to child repo's `master` .
**script used for master
**

```
#!/bin/bash
git init
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/username/file.git
cd file
git submodule update --remote
git commit -a -m "commit in both submodule"
git push -u origin
```

above script work for for parent repo's `master` to child repo's `master` like wise
I want for parent repo's `stage` to child repo's `stage` as well.

**I even tried using multiple commands :-
git push -u origin stage
git config push.default current
git config push.default upstream

none of them were working
**

Answer (score 0):

Well I prepared a script that works fine for branch to branch commits/push

```
################ STAGE
#########################################

#!/bin/bash

#git init
git init

#git clone repo stage including submodules

git clone -b stage --recurse-submodules git@github.com:orgs/file.git

#change directory -repo
cd file

#update the remote ie tag/commits
git submodule update --remote

#add commit 
git commit -a -m "commit in stage submodules"

#git push 
git push -u origin stage
```

Answer (score 0):

`git init` + `git clone` means you are cloning a nested Git repository (and its potntial submodules) inside a new local Git repository.

I would not recommend that approach.

Simply:

- clone your repository directly at the right branch as you do:

  ```
  git clone -b stage --recurse-submodules git@github.com:orgs/file.git
  cd file
  git submodule update --remote
  ```
- Then go inside the submodule you need from the parent repository file

  ```
  cd aSubmodule (check your `file/.gitmodules` file for the list of submodules you currently have)
  git switch stage
  # work, add, commit push
  ```
- Then go back to your main parent repository named 'file', and record the new submodule state

  ```
  cd ..
  # add, commit and push
  ```